# Insert Thymeleaf fragments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm migrating a Spring Boot 1 application to Spring Boot 2.
In the original application I'm seeing a lot of pieces like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

  <th:block th:include="fragments/script :: actionsMenu-js"/>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  });
```

With Thymeleaf 3 being used now this no longer seems to work even after changing the include to insert:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

  <th:block th:insert="~{fragments/script :: actionsMenu-js}"/>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  });
```

The block is not inserted and the Javascript is not correct, I'm getting:

```
messages:180 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I could go and edit all the pages and place the block outside of the script but I'd prefer an approach that requires less refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you use the TEXT syntax instead?

```
[# th:insert="~{fragments/script :: actionsMenu-js}" /]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick! The indentation could use a little to make the final script a bit more readable but that not a problem.